# OpenCV not properly saving image in imwrite

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing, bitmap

I'm trying to debayer a grayscale image using OpenCV on Ubuntu 16.04 with QtCreator / g++.

My code is the following

```
img=cv::Mat(im->get_ResY(),im->get_ResX(),CV_8UC1,(void*)im->get_Buffer());
cv::Mat imgDebayer=cv::Mat(im->get_ResY(),im->get_ResX(),CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(img,imgDebayer,CV_BayerRG2RGB);

...do some more stuff...

cv::imwrite(imgFilename.toStdString(),img);
cv::imwrite(imgFilenameD.toStdString(),imgDebayer);
```

img is written to a grayscale Bitmap that looks fine. There is a second bitmap under the Filename stored in imgFilenameD but it is only 1.1 kB and I can't open it.

Also when I debug the images look somewhat wrong. In the following Image I stopped after the second line.Why is it two channels per image?

[image: debugger view]

Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: not sure whether this holds for imwrite too, but similar behaviour happens if videowriter does not have access to opencv_ffmpeg dll file.

Comment: I voted for closing the question because of "why this code is not working" is not exactly SO question. Besides that the debugger shows that the last executed statement has overridden a bunch of variables. That is something to look at and the source of that is above. The destination of the last executed conversion overrides some other buffers and pointers. C++.